# How to reference some information from another database entry in firebase realtime database with some informattion from the c

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've a firebase entry like this:

```
ID111
     nconfirmations: 4
```

Antoher one like this:

```
ID222
     sender_identifier: 111
```

I want to make a firebase rule that would reference the ID111 content once ID222 is set as the one that is able to read.

I tried with this:

```
{
   "rules": {
     "Chat": {
       "$uid": {
         ".read":  "auth!=null
          && ($uid.contains(data.child('sender_identifier').val()
          && (root.child('Chat/'ID'+root.child('Chat/$uid/sender_identifier').val()/nconfirmations').val()>=2)) ",
```

For

```
$uid.contains(data.child('sender_identifier').val()
```

I get to do the mentioned limitation, of just ID222 being the one that can read as it has "111", but if I do that, it looks like I can no longer reference any more entries with data, at this point data only refers to the ID222 entry.

I have tried to access the content with a root path, as shown in the rule but it just doesn't fly.

If the rule were to work properly I guess it should give the intended result as `'ID'+root.child('Chat/$uid/sender_identifier').val()` should return "ID111".

How could this be done? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

This looks syntactically incorrect:

```
root.child('Chat/'ID'+root.child('Chat/$uid/sender_identifier').val()/nconfirmations').val()
```

My best guess is that you're trying to do:

root.child('Chat/ID'+root.child('Chat/$uid/sender_identifier').val()+'/nconfirmations').val()

Which would use the value from path `/Chat/ID.../nconfirmations` in the validation, with `...` being the values read from `/Chat/$uid/sender_identifier`.

If that's not the problem, please update your question with the minimal complete code that is reading the data, and the actual JSON you're validating against as text. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).